Unwanted addon path in Odoo running in Docker
I have been running Odoo using a docker compose with an odoo image (Created based on odoo Dockerfile and copy the source code cloned from github) and a postgre image. My odoo.conf specify the addons paths of:
[options]
addons_path = /opt/odoo/odoo/addons, /mnt/extra-addons, /opt/odoo/add-ons

And for most of the time using this container, the addons work perfectly. But recently, I have a problem of appearing unwanted extra addons:
2024-08-26 07:50:00,106 1 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/opt/odoo/odoo/addons', '/root/.local/share/Odoo/addons/17.0', '/mnt/extra-addons', '/opt/odoo/addons']

The addons is '/root/.local/share/Odoo/addons/17.0'. The problem is I don't know where the addon come from and if it safe to create a volume. Does it mean a cache or some things?
My full docker compose is:
version: '3.0'

services:
  odoo:
    build: .
    container_name: odoo
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - ./config:/etc/odoo
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
      - ./odoo:/opt/odoo
      - ./abc:/root/.local/share/Odoo
    environment:
      - HOST=db
      - USER=odoo
      - PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    restart: always
    networks:
        - odoo-network
    command: ["-u","Hosting"]


  db:
    image: postgres:13
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    networks:
        - odoo-network
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
        - "5050:80"
    networks:
        - odoo-network


networks:
  odoo-network:

My Docker file is:
FROM ubuntu:jammy

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-xo", "pipefail", "-c"]

ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8

# Retrieve the target architecture to install the correct wkhtmltopdf package
ARG TARGETARCH

RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        dirmngr \
        fonts-noto-cjk \
        gnupg \
        libssl-dev \
        node-less \
        npm \
        python3-magic \
        python3-num2words \
        python3-odf \
        python3-pdfminer \
        python3-pip \
        python3-phonenumbers \
        python3-pyldap \
        python3-qrcode \
        python3-renderpm \
        python3-setuptools \
        python3-slugify \
        python3-vobject \
        python3-watchdog \
        python3-xlrd \
        python3-xlwt \
        xz-utils \
        gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu \
        build-essential \
        libreadline-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        flex \
        bison && \
    if [ -z "${TARGETARCH}" ]; then \
        TARGETARCH="$(dpkg --print-architecture)"; \
    fi; \
    WKHTMLTOPDF_ARCH=${TARGETARCH} && \
    case ${TARGETARCH} in \
    "amd64") WKHTMLTOPDF_ARCH=amd64 && WKHTMLTOPDF_SHA=967390a759707337b46d1c02452e2bb6b2dc6d59  ;; \
    "arm64")  WKHTMLTOPDF_SHA=90f6e69896d51ef77339d3f3a20f8582bdf496cc  ;; \
    "ppc64le" | "ppc64el") WKHTMLTOPDF_ARCH=ppc64el && WKHTMLTOPDF_SHA=5312d7d34a25b321282929df82e3574319aed25c  ;; \
    esac \
    && curl -o wkhtmltox.deb -sSL https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6.1-3/wkhtmltox_0.12.6.1-3.jammy_${WKHTMLTOPDF_ARCH}.deb \
    && echo ${WKHTMLTOPDF_SHA} wkhtmltox.deb | sha1sum -c - \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ./wkhtmltox.deb \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* wkhtmltox.deb

# install latest postgresql-client and libpq-dev
RUN echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ jammy-pgdg main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
    && GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
    && export GNUPGHOME \
    && repokey='B97B0AFCAA1A47F044F244A07FCC7D46ACCC4CF8' \
    && gpg --batch --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys "${repokey}" \
    && gpg --batch --armor --export "${repokey}" > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/pgdg.gpg.asc \
    && gpgconf --kill all \
    && rm -rf "$GNUPGHOME" \
    && apt-get update  \
    && apt-get install -y python3-dev python3-psycopg2 libpq-dev \
    && apt-get install libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev -y\
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y postgresql-client libpq-dev \
    && apt-get install python3-cffi -y\
    && rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
    


# Install rtlcss (on Debian buster)
RUN npm install -g rtlcss

COPY ./odoo /opt/odoo
COPY ./addons /mnt/extra-addons
COPY ./config /etc/odoo
#
#
RUN chown -R root /opt/odoo \
    && chown -R root /mnt/extra-addons  \
    && chown -R root /etc/odoo

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install  -r /opt/odoo/requirements.txt


# ENTRYPOINT [ "ls","/opt" ]
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3","/opt/odoo/odoo-bin", "-c","/etc/odoo/odoo.conf" ]

